# kendo ui treemap: no capacity for zoom/drill-down?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, treemap

Does the Kendo UI treemap widget have the capacity for zooming and drill-down the way d3 treemaps can?

A static Kendo UI treemap:

- http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treemap/index

Zoom-able d3 treemaps:

- https://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/
- http://bl.ocks.org/ganeshv/6a8e9ada3ab7f2d88022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe the Kendo treemap widget does that out of the box. It does not even expose an event for handling tile clicks. In theory you could build that functionality yourself. You'd have to use the `template` property to create custom tile markup, which will make the tiles clickable. Then use the `dataItem` method, or your own logic, to get a reference to the selected data. With that you could apply a filter to the treemap's datasource, which drills the data down. And finally you'll have to rebind the the treemap. But even with all of that you would not get the snazzy zoom-in animation that D3 shows when you click.